# How to export tangent data from blender with python

Tags: python

I an trying to implement normal mapping in opengl es for which i need the per vertex tangent data. Is there some means to get that from python blender api

Comment: you will need tangent and bitangent, and also UV coords of vertices. The first is answered in the duplicite, how to get the UVs is here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/19727/7777

Comment: Thnks for the suggestion